# Delphi and Indy - TCPServer OnExecute strange behavior

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tcp, indy

I have the following code, "adapted" from Lebeau's answer in another post:  [Delphi XE2 / Indy TIdTCPServer / "Connection reset by peer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070968/delphi-xe2-indy-tidtcpserver-connection-reset-by-peer)

```
type
  TClient = class(TObject)
  public
    Host: String;                 
    Queue: TIdThreadSafeStringList;
  end;

var
  Clients: TThreadList;

function TMain.HostOnTList(const Host: String): Pointer;
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TList;
begin
  Result := nil;
  List := Clients.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
      if (TClient(List[I]).Host = Host) then
      begin
        Result := List[I];
        Break;
      end;
  finally
    Clients.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  Hosts: Array[0..4] of String = (
    'HOST1', 'HOST2', 'HOST3', 'HOST4, 'HOST5'
  );
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TList;
  Client: TClient;
begin
  Clients := TThreadList.Create;
  Clients.Duplicates := dupAccept;
  for I := Low(Hosts) to High(Hosts) do
  begin
    Client := TClient.Create;
    Client.Host := Hosts[I];
    Client.Queue := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
    Clients.Add(Client);
    Client := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TList;
begin
  if TCPServer.Active Then
    TCPServer.Active := False;
  List := Clients.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
      TClient(List[I]).Free;
  finally
    Clients.UnlockList;
    Clients.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Host: String;  // Host String
  CIdx: Pointer; // Client Pointer
begin
  ... (get context hostname)
  CIdx := HostOnTList(Host);
  if (CIdx <> nil) then
    AContext.Data := TClient(CIdx);
  else
    ... (disconnect client)
end;

procedure TMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  List: TList;
  Host: String;
  Client: TClient;
begin
  Host := '';
  Client := TClient(AContext.Data);
  List := Clients.LockList;
  try
    Host := Client.Host;
    if (Host <> '') then
    begin
      Client.Queue := nil;
      AContext.Data := nil;
    end;
  finally
    Clients.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.idTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TStringList;
begin
  Client := TClient(AContext.Data);
  ...
  List := Client.Queue.Lock;
  try
    while List.Count > 0 do
    begin
      WriteLn(List[0]);
      List.Delete(0);
    end;
  finally
    Client.Queue.Unlock;
  end;
  ...
end;

function TMain.SendMessage(const Host, Msg: String): Boolean;
var
  List: TList;
  CIdx: Pointer;
begin
  Result := False;
  CIdx := HostOnTList(Host);
  if (CIdx <> nil) then
  begin
    List := TCPServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      TClient(CIdx).Queue.Add(Msg);
      Result := True;
    finally
      TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But is happening a strange behavior... Client can connect, but once disconnect and try to connect again, it is been disconnected.

I tried to comment the lines of code until find the problem, and it happens with this line:  "List := Client.Queue.Lock;" inside idTCPServerExecute procedure.

Please, anyone knows what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `OnConnect` handler assign `AContext.Data := Client;`?  You did not show that, but your `OnExecute` handler is expecting it (the code I provided in the linked discussion does that assignment). And do you have a `OnDisconnect` handler that frees the `TClient` and `Queue` objects? That being said, I would suggest deriving `TClient` from `TIdServerContext` and assign that to the server's `ContextClass` property, and get rid of the `Clients` list altogether. The server have its own public `Contexts` list that keeps track of connected clients.

Comment: I see you are still using your own `Clients` list, instead of eliminating it like I suggested in the other discussion you linked to.  I do strongly recommend you get rid of your ownlist, since you are just duplicating what `TIdTCPServer` already does for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, actually my code is some different, because I need to have a populated list of tclients, and change their status OnConnect and OnDisconnect events. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555342/threadlist-of-tobject-with-delphi-how-to-populate. But I am assigning AContext.Data := Client on connect and AContext.Data := nil on disconnect. I will update the code in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pre-allocating `TClient` objects at startup and matching them to clients when they connect.  The problem is that your `OnDisconnect` code is setting the `TClient.Queue` member to nil (without actually freeing the `Queue` object, thus leaking it) but leaving the `TClient` object in the list.  If a client re-connects, the `OnExecute` event crashes trying to access the now-nil `Queue`.

If you really want to re-use `TClient` objects, then change your `FormDestroy` and `OnDisconnect` events to this instead:

```
procedure TMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TList;
  Client: TClient;
begin
  if TCPServer.Active Then
    TCPServer.Active := False;
  List := Clients.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Client := TClient(List[I]);
      Client.Queue.Free;
      Client.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Clients.UnlockList;
    Clients.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Client: TClient;
begin
  Client := TClient(AContext.Data);
  if Client <> nil then
  begin
    Client.Queue.Clear;
    AContext.Data := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you again Mr. Lebeau! I hope this topic can help other people with same problem.